# c# custom uninstaller

Tags: c#, installation, uninstallation

I'm attempting to write a custom uninstaller script; however, I'm stuck at the "programs, and features" dialog. Are there any written documentation as to what registry keys do I need to add in order for my application to be displayed there? Or -alternatively- are there any native WINAPI / .NET functions to create a shurtcut there directly?

Addendum: there are business requirements disallowing me the use of third-party tools, such as the default MSI installer. Provided answer should work on a clean XP virtual machine, w/ .NET 2.0 installed, without referencing to any external .dlls. Thank you.

Comment: Your requirements include not using third-party tools to *create*, or *run* the installer/uninstaller?  Windows installer is installed by default on Windows XP (though it may be an older version than the one VS-generated installers want to use by default).  You may be better off figuring out how to get a real installer builder to build an installer compatible with the version of windows installer XP has by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine MSI installer is the best solution, but if you must, the registry key which is the source of items in add/remove programs dialog is here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

I don't know if there's a good documentation about structure of this key, but I'm sure you can figure it out, it's not so hard